# Laravel Resources doesn't work with model binding on custom url

Tags: laravel, model, resources, auto

If i use this route:

```
Route::resource('monitor', 'UserMonitorController');
```

And then in controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, UserMonitor $userMonitor) {}
```

Which was automatically generated by

```
php artisan make:model -mcr UserMonitor
```

The `$userMonitor` is empty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problem

The reason is using route patch

> /monitor

instead of

> /usermonitor (as controller name)

### Solution

The variable has to be the same as variable in routing. In this case it's automatically generated:

```
php artisan route:list 
PUT|PATCH | api/monitor/{monitor}         | monitor.update    | App\Http\Controllers\UserMonitorController@update
```

So the solution is to change:

```
public function update(Request $request, UserMonitor $userMonitor) {}
```

To:

```
public function update(Request $request, UserMonitor $monitor) {}
```